# localhost:port served content via public facing port with login

Tags: ubuntu, security, localhost

|ubuntu 16.04|
I have an application currently served only locally.

i wish to access this application, after logging in from external location (web browser based).

essentially a container on same machine as localhost application, acting as a gateway for authorised access to the localhost application.

Is this possible?

I am well versed in a few languages but this has me stumped.

Comment: theres a lot that goes into this, from DNS resolution and public IPs to port forwarding and reachability, to implementing a sign-in system for your app and linking them for authentication, and adjusting the application to handle authorization in conjunction with the authentication platform. As it stands your question is too broad, and needs to be refined to tackle each of these items separately, based on the pertinent technologies in use. You will probably want to use another site for the more programming based questions. best of luck.

Comment: From what I understand, two options: 1) use a VPN to connect to your local network, 2) set up  a local HTTP proxy and connect to the server through that proxy.